# How to ensure a variable isn't undefined by the time it's passed into an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a couple of variables into an AJAX request. But it looks like the variables are undefined by the time they're passed into the AJAX request. Here's my JavaScript file:

```
// just testing whereAmI()
$("#test").click(function() {
    whereAmI();
});

myMap = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 12
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    whereAmI();
    getCountryNames();
    modalOpen();
    initialOpenCage();
});

function whereAmI() {
    var myresult = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
    }
    
    function success(position) {
        globalThis.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        globalThis.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        makeMyMap(latitude, longitude);
    }
    
    function error() {
        alert("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}

function getCountryNames() {

    // runs an AJAX call to the correct PHP routine
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/getCountryNames.php",
        type: "GET",
        // sets the correct format of whatever returns to json
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        // if the status of the data returned is "ok", then grabCountryName() is run for each country
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            // call .forEach(grabCountryName) on sorted array
            result.names.forEach(grabCountryName);
        }
        else {
            alert("country names have not successfully loaded");
        }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR + ' ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
};

var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('staticBackdrop'));

function modalOpen() {
    myModal.toggle();
};

function initialOpenCage() {

    // when clicked, runs an AJAX call to the correct PHP routine
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/openCage.php",
        type: "GET",
        // sets the correct format of whatever returns to json
        dataType: "json",
        // passes the correct parameters
        data: {
            lat: globalThis.latitude,
            lng: globalThis.longitude
        },
        success: function(result) {
  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            // if the status of the data returned is "ok", then the data held in results is written into the HTML of the table data cells
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
  
                alert("current location is " + result['data']['results'][0]['formatted']);

                // $('#txtTimeCountry').html(result['data']['countryName']);
                // $('#txtTZ').html(result['data']['timezoneId']);
                // $('#txtSunrise').html(result['data']['dates'][0]['sunrise']);
                // $('#txtSunset').html(result['data']['dates'][0]['sunset']);
  
            }
            else {
          
                alert("openCage response is invalid");
  
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
  
};

// append the country name to the set-country dropdown list
function grabCountryName(countryName) {
    $('#set-country').append(`<option value="${countryName}">${countryName}</option>`);
}

function makeMyMap(mylat, mylng) {
    myMap.panTo(new L.LatLng(mylat, mylng), 12);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.jawg.io/jawg-streets/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?access-token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: '<a href="http://jawg.io" title="Tiles Courtesy of Jawg Maps" target="_blank">&copy; <b>Jawg</b>Maps</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 22,
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        accessToken: '1TnbC1APJLHxYi4rR6zi4okkjWA4bU1XiI6TKzyfXuyd7BI38bnMDX5xjNRP2ZHb'
    }).addTo(myMap);
}

let border = L.geoJSON;

$("#set-country").on('change', function() {
    modalOpen();
    getBorder();
});

function getBorder() {
    // when clicked, runs an AJAX call to the correct PHP routine
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/getCountryBorder.php",
        type: "GET",
        // sets the correct format of whatever returns to json
        dataType: "json",
        // passes the correct parameter
        data: {
        country: $("#set-country").val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        // if the status of the data returned is "ok", then the data held in results is added to myMap
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {

            // clear previous border, then add the selected one
            myMap.removeLayer(border);
            border = L.geoJSON(result['data']).addTo(myMap);
            // pan map to selected country
            myMap.flyToBounds(border);
            
        }
        else {
            
            alert("country border has not successfully loaded");

        }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

I was encountering an issue earlier because latitude and longitude weren't global variables. I fixed this by declaring latitude and longitude both as properties on the globalThis object. But these variables are still being passed into the AJAX request as undefined.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to eat your pizza before it's been delivered.   `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so you need to continue only once its `success` callback has fired.

Comment: What does a `console.log(position)` output in `success()` in `whereAmI()`?

Comment: GeolocationPosition {coords: GeolocationCoordinates, timestamp: 1627989867806}
coords: GeolocationCoordinates {latitude: 51.776716799999996, longitude: 0.589824, altitude: null, accuracy: 869, altitudeAccuracy: null, …}
timestamp: 1627989867806
[[Prototype]]: GeolocationPosition